# Trouble opening an fstream file in c++ (Newbie)

Tags: c++, file-handling, fstream

I'm learning about file handling in C++ and in the part explaining how to open a file it had this:

`ifstream fin( "inputFile.txt" );`

or this:

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open( "inputFile.txt" );
```

My first question is: What does `inputFile.txt` do here?

- Is it simply the name of the file I open?
- If so, what is the role of `.txt`? I've also seen `.bin` used in its place too.
- Since the function's syntax is `open (filename, mode)` and `inputFile.txt` is passed in the filename paramater, why can't we just put a string there without the `.txt`?

I also encountered another problem. When I write this command in visual studio using the `fail()` function, it appears the file doesn't open properly as it sends the `Error - Failed to open` message

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream fin("inputFile.txt"); //open file
    if (fin.fail()) {                   //check if opened properly
        std::cerr << "Error - Failed to open ";
    }
    else { std::cout << "Opened properly"; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs : `Error - Failed to open`

The only case I've noticed it doesn't have a problem is when I pass `filename.txt` as an argument

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream fin("filename.txt"); //open file
    if (fin.fail()) {                  //check if opened properly
        std::cerr << "Error - Failed to open ";
    }
    else { std::cout << "Opened properly"; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs : `Opened properly`

Why is that? In the instructions it had `inputFile.txt` and it doesn't work here.
Also, why does it even matter if it's `inputFile.txt` or `filename.txt`, isn't it just a name?

Sorry for the number of questions, I'm just really confused over this and would really appreciate it if someone could clear this all up for me.

Comment: *Is it simply the name of the file I open?* Yes.

Comment: *If so, what is the role of .txt ? I've also seen .bin used in its place too.* As far as C++ is concerned it has only the meaning you apply to it. If you want a binary file you need to change the openmode.

Comment: _"if so, what is the role of .txt ?"_ Absolutely nothing. It's just part of the file name. `foo.txt`, `bar.tar.gz`, `a.b.c.d.e.f` are all valid file names on any common filesystem.

Comment: *Since the function's syntax is "open (filename, mode)" and "inputFile.txt" is passed in the filename paramater, why can't we just put a string there without the .txt ?* You have to provide the name of the file. If the file name has a .txt on the end you can't leave it out.

Comment: You can only open a file for reading if it exists. Presumably you cannot open `inputFile.txt` and can open `filename.txt` because the former does not exist and the latter does.

Comment: @Brian61354270 This might be a dumb question but how do I know if a file exists or not? To which files percisely am i connecting the fstream objects that I create?

Comment: In a modern muti-process and multi-user system the only way to be sure that a file exists is opening and see if it opens. Any check-first-then-open approach can be interrupted between the check and the potential open and the file deleted or created.

Comment: Side note: When using relative paths, as opposed to absolute paths like `/home/bill/myfile`, make sure you are in the correct [Working Directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). Thinking the program is running in one folder when it's actually running in another trips up a lot of new programmers.

Comment: @user4581301 Ok thanks, I think I'm starting to get the hang of this a bit better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What does inputFile.txt do here?

inputFile.txt allows (in this case) fin to determine what file it’s opening, so yes, it is the name of the file you open.

The role of .txt is the same as the entire file name. For example, if you had 2 inputFile files, one being .txt and one being .bin, you would use the file extension to differentiate which one you’re opening.

If I’m not mistaken, C++ won’t be able to find the file you’re trying to open without the file extension.

## `fail()` function

Try using `is_open()` instead of `fail()`. `fail()` is better for reading/writing status, rather than checking for opening errors. `is_open()` will return a boolean for whether or not the file was successfully opened.

My guess for why filename.txt works but inputFile.txt doesn’t is because fail is not returning reading or writing errors because the file “filename.txt” doesn’t exist.

Hope this helps!

(Source: https://cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/)